# Bootstrap: "has-error" class not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a small form in a system I'm working on which takes in a bank authorization code and updates the account accordingly.

I'm putting the validation in place, starting with trying to submit the form with no code provided.

I'm using the `has-error` class elsewhere without issue, but in this case, it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Bart Foo - Payment Received
            <div class="label label-info pull-right">Transfer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="/Payments/Update/dQyQyALT3kqPRxcxLclKRQ" method="post">
                <div class="form-group has-errror">
                    <label for="ref-code">Please enter the reference number for the Transfer.</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="You must enter a reference code" name="ref-code" class="form-control">
                    <p>
                        <small>The user will see this authorization code in the registration portal.</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Upon approving this payment, a confirmation email will immediately be sent to the user at this address: <code>bart.foo@example.com</code>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                        <input type="submit" value="Approve Payment" class="form-control pull-right btn-default">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result:

[image: has-error]

`has-error` is applied to the container div, which is a `form-group`, and contains an `input` with `form-control` applied. What have I missed?

Comment: There might be some nesting/cascading rules that are being overlooked.  ALSO - you need to confirm that the class is even being applied to DOM object you want it applied to.  Have you done that in the inspector?

Comment: Yeah, that's happened to me before! I sourced that HTML by right clicking on the node in the inspector and using Copy HTML, just so I can be sure it's been applied. I'm didn't see any sign of nesting warnings in the bootstrap documentation, is there another way I could look for problems with that, or do I need to just start removing code and try and find it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is simple: you wrote `has-errror` in your code instead of `has-error`

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
```

### [Working bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/5XYzWSN37S)

Comment: Lol - brilliant! I actually double checked that I'd used the right class as well and still didn't see that. It might be about time for a dev break I think...

Comment: @Octopoid I dont even know how i spotted that, as soon as I got to the question i spotted it and for a moment I thought I was wrong. Take a break, it might help